# upsert script is not working

Tags: php, mongodb, upsert

I'm trying to get upsert to work and getting no results

I have three variables I'm posting before this script. If I update, I get result, but I want to upsert and am getting no results.

Here is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST)){
    if($array){
        $doc = $collection->update(
            array(
                '$set' => array(
                    '_id' => new MongoId(),
                    'organization' => $mysql_org_name,
                    'purch_code' => $mysql_purch_code,
                    'contentname' => $mysql_order_item_name,
                    array('upsert' => true)
                )
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Just noticed that you question is tagged as `mongodb` but all your variable names contain `mysql`. Unless a) you're migrating between DBs or b) these are references to stuff that's stored separately in a MySQL DB, I would rename them. Also, I'd suggest you edit the title of your question to include which DB type you're actually using.

Comment: @cyfur01 You are correct, the vars are predefined your MySQL_ since I am taking them from 2 MySQL queries and trying to upsert them into mongo. I understand the confusion, but they are just names and only used for this purpose and only in this script. I'm taking vars from my WP WooCommerce tables and copying them an App I've developed against mongodb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Update expects 3 argument arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.update.php). You've only passed one.

First, you've included you options as part of the `$set` array. They should be passed as a separate argument after the update clause.

Also, you don't have a match criteria (i.e., a query statement to select which item(s) to update). When using upsert and `$set`, a new item would be created with the fields from both arrays([see the relevant documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-behavior)).

Finally, if you don't specify a value for `_id`, Mongo will generate one for you.

---

If, for instance, you wanted to match based on the `organization` field:

```
if(isset($_POST)){
    if($array){
        $doc = $collection->update(
            array('organization' => $mysql_org_name),
            array(
                '$set' => array(
                    'purch_code' => $mysql_purch_code,
                    'contentname' => $mysql_order_item_name,
                )
            ),
            array('upsert' => true)
        );
    }
}
```

If this matches one or more entries, only the `purch_code` and `contentname` fields will be updated on the first matching object (to update multiple entries, you'd have to specify `'multiple'=>true` in your options array). If nothing matches, a new entry would be inserted with:

1. A generated `_id`
2. All of the match criteria values (i.e., `organization`)
3. All of the update operator values (i.e., `purch_code` and `contentname`)

Comment: Great explanation @cyfur01. It still does not work, but not your issue. I have issues before I get to this part of the code. I'm still marking your solution as correct because you have really done a great job explaining the upsert process. Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

You have variable $set on single quote
    '$set' => array(

Comment: `$set` is a MongoDB operator, not a variable. It has to be in single quotes to prevent PHP from performing sting substitution.